# ¿Como eliminar en ciclos los guiones y puntos de un String en PHP?

Tags: php

tengo el siguiente problema, poseo un arreglo de 5 String, algunos de los cuales terminan en guion, con espacio, punto o alguna combinación entre los 3.

Ejemplos de String:

- 'String de ejemplo 1  '
- 'String de ejemplo 2. '
- 'String de ejemplo 3-'
- 'String de ejemplo 4.- '
- 'String de ejemplo 5 .- .'

Para remover eso implemente una función que se llama por cada String que hace lo siguiente:

```
function depurar($cadena) {
//Quitar espacios en blanco al principio y final de la cadena.
$cadena = trim($cadena);

for($contador = 1; $contador <= 5; $contador++) {
    //Remover guiones al final de la cadena.
    $cadena = rtrim($cadena, '-');
    echo $cadena = rtrim($cadena, '-') . '<br>';
    //Quitar espacios en blanco al final de la cadena.
    $cadena = rtrim($cadena);
    //Quitar comas al final de la cadena.
    $cadena = rtrim($cadena, ',');
    echo $cadena = rtrim($cadena, ',') . '<br>';
    //Quitar espacios en blanco al final de la cadena.
    $cadena = rtrim($cadena);
    //Quitar puntocoma al final de la cadena.
    $cadena = rtrim($cadena, ';');
    echo $cadena = rtrim($cadena, ';') . '<br>';
    //Quitar espacios en blanco al final de la cadena.
    $cadena = rtrim($cadena);
    //Quitar punto al final de la cadena.
    $cadena = rtrim($cadena, '.');
    echo $cadena = rtrim($cadena, '.') . '<br>';
    //Quitar espacios en blanco al final de la cadena.
    $cadena = rtrim($cadena);
    //Quitar dospuntos al final de la cadena.
    $cadena = rtrim($cadena, ':');
    echo $cadena = rtrim($cadena, ':') . '<br>';
}

 return $cadena;
}
```

Lo ideal es que las salidas sean el String con solo textos, pero no funciona. Gracias por su atención.

**Actualización**

Hay un par de String que poseen estos caracteres en alguna parte de los String, esto hace que no pueda usar solo un str_replace ya que los elimina de todo el String.

Por ejemplo:

- 'Strings: ¿Que es un String? - septiembre 2019. '

Comment: Hola, para eliminar todos los puntos y guiones puedes usar `$cadena=trim(str_replace(array('-','.'), '', $cadena));`, puedes empezar por ahí.

Comment: Agradezco mencionaras eso porque lo pase por alto al hacer la pregunta, algunos de los String son del estilo 'Texto de ejemplo: Ejemplo 1.' Olvidé agregarlo a los ejemplos. Por eso no puedo usar los str_replace(). Actualizo la pregunta con ese mismo ejemplo.

Comment: Entiendo, estoy consciente de que no responde directamente la pregunta, lo vi cuando dijiste "...los textos terminan...", pero el siguiente paso es solamente hacer un `substring`, tomar los últimos caracteres de la cadena y aplicar las funciones.

Comment: Si siempre tienes un elemento al final del **string** lo puedes hacer con un **substr** así **substr($cadena, 0,-1)** en este caso no te haria falta aplicarle un **trim()** para quitar el espacio. Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
$rege = '/[^a-z0-9]+$/i'; // expresion regular

// arreglo con datos
$data = array('String de ejemplo 1  ',
 'String de ejemplo 2. ',
  'String de ejemplo 3-',
 'String de ejemplo 4.- ',
 'String de ejemplo 5 .- .');

foreach($data as $value){

    $res = preg_replace($rege, "", $value); // remplazamos todo excepto letras numero

   echo $res."\n";
}
```

[demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/829da681bd9c5c18c95417739f6c1663583557cc)

Comment: Esta es la manera correcta. No solo eliminará los puntos o guiones, sino que cualquier otro posible caracter especial.

Answer (score 0):

Al final esta es la función que me desarrolle que funciona para resolver mi problema, agradezco a quienes intentaron darle solución puesto que me oriente en sus comentarios para la realización de la misma. La comparto a modo de otro ejemplo más para quienes lean la pregunta en un futuro.

```
function depurar($cadena) {

    /*Paso 1. Se guarda en una variable el largo de la cadena original luego de un trim.*/
    $cadena_largo = strlen( trim($cadena) );

    /*Paso 2. Se recortan los ultimos 5 caracteres de la cadena original con trim.*/
    $caracteres_recortados = substr( trim($cadena), -6 );

    /*Paso 3. Remover los caracteres que se desean eliminar de caracteres_recortados.*/
    $reemplazos = array(
        '-'             => '',
        '.'             => '',
        ','             => '',
        ';'             => ''
    );
    /*Paso 4. Limpiar el trozo final de la cadena*/
    $caracteres_recortados = strtr( $caracteres_recortados , $reemplazos );

    /*Paso 5. Si existen caracteres en el String recortado despúes de la limpieza.*/
    if( strlen(rtrim( $caracteres_recortados )) > 0 ) {

        /*Paso 6a1. Guardar la primera parte del titulo en un String descontando los 6 caracteres.*/
        $cadena_principio = substr( trim($cadena), 0, ($cadena_largo - 6));

        /*Paso 6a2. Concatenar la cadena_principio con los caracteres en una nueva cadena*/
        $cadena_nueva = $cadena_principio . $caracteres_recortados;

    } else { /*De no existir caracteres*/

        /*Paso 6b1. Guardar en cadena_nueva la cadena descontando los caracteres*/
        $cadena_nueva = substr( trim($cadena), 0, ($cadena_largo - 6));
    }

    /*Paso 7. Retornar la cadena limpiada*/
    return $cadena_nueva;
}
```